# project lombok annotations with intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm not sure if it's something wrong with intellij or I don't understand something but when I wrote code without comment 
like this, I can't add Lombok annototations but when

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;



@Entity
public class...
```

I add comment to class like this

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Created by
 */

@Entity
public class...
```

Now I can use Lombok annotations. I use jdk 8 with IntelliJ and this is very weird for me

Comment: Shut down everything and restart. Processing comments is evil! (Yeah grunt, I am talking about you also!)

Comment: Do you have a lombok plugin version which match your intellij version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am currently using Intellij and lombok. I have no issues, you need the @Data annotation for lombok at the top of your class. Also you need to install the lombok plugin in intellij as documeted on the lombok page https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij. You should then be able to access the getter and setter methods of your variables.

I suggest you look at the project lombok documentation for the different annotations.